# jQuery/AJAX/XML stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I've tried this a bunch of different ways, stuck on the call to XML data.  I've debugged it, code comes out clean, but when I execute, it does nothing.

Here is the JS

```
//----------------------THE MAIL FORM---------------------------

function mailMe(form) {
    return true;
}


//----------------------ADD ITEM---------------------------

function addItem() {
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    $("#itemCont").append("<div id='item" + id + "' class='service'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Item:  </span><select name='ITEM" + id + "' style='width: 300px;'><option value=' '>Select an item...</option></select><span style='font-weight: bold;'>  S/N:  </span><input name='SN' type='text' style='width: 100px;'><p><span style='font-weight: bold;'>  Parts:  </span></p><div id='partCont'></div><a href='#' onClick='addPart(test.xml); return false;'>Add Part</a><div class='ri'><p><a href='#' onClick='removeItem(\"#item" + id + "\"); return false;'>Remove Item</a></p></div></div>");
    id = (id - 1) + 2;
    document.getElementById("id").value = id;
}

function removeItem(id) {
    $(id).remove();
}


//----------------------ADD PART---------------------------

function addPart(url) {
    var pn = document.getElementById("pn").value;
    var xmlhttp;
    var txt, x, xx, i;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            txt = "<select name='test'><option value=''>Make a selection...<option>";
            x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("part");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                txt = txt + "<option value='";
                xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("lawson");
                try {
                    txt = txt + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "'>";
                }
                catch (er) {
                    txt = txt + "'>";
                }
            }
            xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("desc");
            try {
                txt = txt + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</option>";
            }
            catch (et) {
                txt = txt + "</option>";
            }
        }
    };
    txt = txt + "</select>";
    $("#partCont").append("p);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    pn = (pn - 1) + 2;
    document.getElementById("pn").value = pn;
}


function removePart(id) {
    $(id).remove();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

    <title>EIS Kodak - Service Parts Form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="addInput.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav">

        <h1>Service Parts Form</h1>

    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <p><a href="#" onClick="addItem(); return false;">Add Item</a></p>

        <form id="form1" action="mailto:letichiak.broderick@kodak.com?subject=Service Parts Form" method="post" onsubmit="return mailMe( this.form )" enctype="text/plain">

            <input type="hidden" id="id" value="1">

            <input type="hidden" id="pc" value="1">

            <input type="hidden" id="pn" value="1">

            <div id="itemCont"></div>

            <p style="margin-top: 20px;">

                <input type="submit" value="   Submit   " >

                <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">

            </p>

        </form>
    </div><!--Content-->

 </body>

 </html>
```

And the XML:

```
<service>
    <part>
        <desc>Part 1 Description</desc>
        <lawson>L#1</lawson>
        <partnum>P#1</partnum>
        <category>Category1</category>
    </part>
    <part>
        <desc>Part 2 Description</desc>
        <lawson>L#2</lawson>
        <partnum>P#2</partnum>
        <category>Category2</category>
    </part>
    <part>
        <desc>Part 3 Description</desc>
        <lawson>L#3</lawson>
        <partnum>P#3</partnum>
        <category>Category3</category>
    </part>
    <part>
        <desc>Part 4 Description</desc>
        <lawson>L#4</lawson>
        <partnum>P#4</partnum>
        <category>Category3</category>
    </part>
</service>
```

I'm either missing something in the syntax or I don't know what I'm doing.  Or both?

Comment: Why aren't you using the jQuery ajax methods?

Comment: I was building this form before I got in to jQuery and only added it later.  I guess I'll look in to that.

But I can't find what's wrong with the code.  It should work, it just doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt = txt + "</select>";
```

Shouldn't that line be inside the AJAX success function and also the append? Or I am missing something here. Are you atleast getting the AJAX to post properly and get the response data?

Comment: append is suppossed to read as the "txt" variable.  I was putting a text string in there just to see if it would post.

Comment: I've actually got it to the point now where it posts "undefined" in the <div> where the text is supposed to go.  Better than nothing I guess?

Comment: So you are saying that the AJAX function is not actually posting to the URL? Is that right? If yes, then which URL are you trying to post to? Are you sure that it is not a cross-domain issue? Just trying to guess here.

Comment: The spot where the data and the text string is supposed to post, only the text "undefined" shows up.  But I don't know what is "undefined" or what causes that to appear.